# Is it possible to enable Ray Tracing on non Beta Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been running Minecraft with Ray Tracing turned on but Beta version, is it possible to get Ray Tracing on in the non beta version yet?

Comment: i am pinging you so u can check the updated answer. *ping ping ping!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes!

As of 1.16.200, raytracing is a feature in normal versions of the game! You can buy content from the marketplace that features raytracing resource packs, although I am unsure if they are part of normal resource packs that anyone can make/download for free. **Do keep in mind the hardware/software requirements still apply (Windows 10 & a Graphics Card that supports Ray Tracing).**

### Outdated Answer

***No***

*RTX can only be run on Windows 10 edition with graphics cards that support RTX. You must be in a beta.*

Comment: Do I need to use their worlds or can I create my own realm?

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat they should come with a resource pack that can be used on anything - worlds, servers, realms